# 'Tkinter' not defined, yet it's being imported

Tags: python, tkinter

So like I have this code I am editing/modifying to make it work, any help?

heres my error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Injector.py", line 42, in <module>
    f = Injector()
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Injector.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.__openInjector()
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Injector.py", line 33, in __openInjector
    Tkinter.Button(root, text='Inject!', command=self.runInjectorCode).pack()
NameError: name 'Tkinter' is not defined
```

and here is my code:

```
try:
    # for Python2
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    # for Python3
    from tkinter import *

class Injector:

    def __openInjector(self):
        root = Tk()
        root.geometry('600x400')
        root.title('Toontown Rewritten Injector')
        root.resizable(False, False)

    def __init__(self):
        self.code = ''
        self.__openInjector()

    def runInjectorCode(self):
        exec(self.code.get(1.0, 'end'), globals())

    def __openInjector(self):
        root = Tk()
        root.geometry('600x400')
        root.title('Toontown Rewritten Injector')
        root.resizable(False, False)

        frame = Frame(root)
        self.code = Text(frame, width=70, height=20)
        self.code.pack(side='left')

        Tkinter.Button(root, text='Inject!', command=self.runInjectorCode).pack()

        scroll = Scrollbar(frame)
        scroll.pack(fill='y', side='right')
        scroll.config(command=self.code.yview)

        self.code.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
        frame.pack(fill='y')

f = Injector()
f.go()
```

please help I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I am very new to this python stuff and i am modify another code that didn't work at all. But this has to somehow

Comment: According to the error message, `Tkinter` is missing which means your imports are not working. Double check that your environment contains `Tkinter`

Comment: His imports are right but he imported `*` not `Tkinter` itself, and then tries to reference it.

Answer (score 5):

```
Tkinter.Button(root, text='Inject!', command=self.runInjectorCode).pack()
```

should be

```
Button(root, text='Inject!', command=self.runInjectorCode).pack()
```

When you type the line `from Tkinter import *` it means that you no longer have to refer to them as `Tkinter.Thing()` rather you should now refer to them as `Thing()` directly

[See this](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm) for a quick read about how to import python modules as it will save you a LOT of debugging in the future

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Injector.py", line 43, in <module>
    f.go()
AttributeError: 'Injector' object has no attribute 'go'

Comment: your class has no function `go` I would suggest playing with simpler code before moving to more advanced class truckers like these...

Comment: but is it possible to fix?

Comment: yes, it will be fairly trivial once you understand your code

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to your second problem which is f.go(). What you want to do is since f.go isnt a function you most likely just want to run the injector so I would replace f.go with just f which should run your code :)